# PHP read Array and Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I got this array and I want to read the value of `"copy01"` (in `img_4e77e508ab518_197.jpg`).

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:6:"copy01";s:25:"img_4e77e508ab518_197.jpg";s:6:"copy02";s:24:"img_4e77e508ab518_80.jpg";s:6:"copy03";s:24:"img_4e77e508ab518_36.jpg";} ) )
```

This is a `print_r($dataOne)` and `$data_One` is a query from the database in WP.

```
$dataOne = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE umeta_id = '22'");
```

Comment: Did you try `$dataOne->copy01`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo unserialize($dataOne[0]->meta_value)->copy01;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with a serialized object as the 0th element of the array.

`$normalobject = unserialize($dataOne[0]);` and `var_dump($normalobject);` to get an idea of how to read the value.

Answer (score -1):

```
$dataOne[0]->copy01
```

how about that?

Comment: i see i may have missed unserialize